# Where did the Community Wiki option go?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I tried to mark a post CW, but I can't find the check box that used to do that. Has it moved, been removed, or is it just my head that's not on straight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Community Wiki (CW) mean?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-does-community-wiki-cw-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not your head. :)

The Community Wiki option has been removed from general use and is now a mod-only option. If it really needs to be CW, I think the way to do it is to flag it for moderator attention.

---

Found the source:

> 2010-10-14: Questions can no longer be turned community wiki by non-moderators

from the in the [Recent feature changes on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/150909) list which links to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) by [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles).

---

Update (just noticed this): You can still mark your *answers* "Community Wiki", which still means "owned by the community" with the same low rep threshold for others to edit (and no rep, only badges, for the poster).

Comment: The post makes a great point about CW being a dangerous/damaging option in most cases.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yeah. It gets rid of the "should this question be CW?" question.

Comment: We had some serious discussion about that early on.  I'm not sad to be rid of the question.