# How should we use Community Wiki? [2012]

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, list-questions

In the beginning, RPG.SE was [Community Wiki](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-does-community-wiki-cw-mean) crazy.  [We used it for everything](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1). [We have an old Meta question on what to use CW for](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/how-should-we-use-community-wiki). But then we realized list questions were bad and CW was being used as a dumping ground for bad questions. So [now CW is anathema](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/where-did-the-community-wiki-option-go). [Some hunt down and kill old CW questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-we-be-closing-old-community-wiki-questions), [annoying old users](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/are-there-any-role-playing-games-that-have-spawned-comic-books-or-vice-versa). But some cases have come up recently, I think, where we should consider what CW should be used for. So here's a new question to obsolete the old - what *should* we use CW for in 2012?

Comment: This question has been renamed after the fact to call it "Part II" to make its position in a presently three-part series self-evident.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some exploratory "list" questions that are a good fit. There's "laundry" lists, which are just long lists of simple game names or whatever.  Then there's design exploration questions like Brian's [Useful mental frameworks during character creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/useful-mental-frameworks-during-character-creation) seem like perfectly good content for the site. Design exploration falls under "by experts for experts," IMO. ENWorld is keeping a page like this (http://www.enworld.org/index.php?page=dnd5e) but that's not community contribution, it's curated by the ENWorld guy.

Edit: nowadays we've decided list questions are just off topic, instead. Same with "design exploration" that's not tightly scoped.

Also, I think we should consider a "D&D 5e; What we know so far" CW to prevent bad Q&A like [Will a 5th edition of Dungeons & Dragons be released?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/will-a-5th-edition-of-dungeons-dragons-be-released) and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/how-will-the-play-testing-for-dd-5th-edition-work from erupting, while still gathering useful info and driving people to the site.  I think collecting info like this also counts as a good "by experts, for experts" use.

Edit: And in a separate newer question, we've decided not this either. [Would Community Wiki be useful for questions about the “current” state of something?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/would-community-wiki-be-useful-for-questions-about-the-current-state-of-someth)

What to NOT use it for - everything else. I think it should be a safety valve for things extremely useful for the site GOAL that don't quite fit the usual site FORMAT.

Comment: I think the D&D 5 question is a great fit for CW. I wouldn't object to the other use (i.e. lists with sizable original content).

Comment: I think it's also important that the lists are finite, in the sense they can't keep growing. Take a look at this question, and the answer that's become a CW: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/what-plot-points-are-missing-in-the-harry-potter-movies-that-are-in-the-novels

I think that's not so bad as it should encourage others to refine it.